# Use closure to sum numbers

Tags: javascript, closures

Currently I have a closure in JS that looks like the following:

```
var addTo = function(num){

   var add = function(inner){
      return inner + num;
   };
   return add;
};

var sum = new addTo(1);
```

My goal is to use the above closure to compute the sum from `1` all the way to `100` (i.e. `sum = 1+2+3+...+99+100`). Any help? I know a loop is needed, but am unsure of what should go inside the loop and how to use closure to achieve the goal. Thanks guys.

Comment: The task is super vague. If you need a help with some assignment - you better post it, otherwise if you just made the task for yourself - try to formalize it even further.

Comment: I made the task myself. I'm just wondering whether this can be done using closure.

Comment: do something like below 

var sum = 0;

for(var i=1; i <= 100; i++){

    sum += parseInt(nums[i]);

}

alert(sum);

Comment: "I made the task myself. I'm just wondering whether this can be done using closure." --- you better formalize the task, at the moment it makes very few sense. Closure is simply a function with some captured variables.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure exactly what a closure has to do with all this.

Comment: `var sum = 0; for (var i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) { sum = addTo(sum)(i); }` --- but it all makes no sense, really.

Comment: Thank you. @zerkms

Answer (score 1):

> Currently I have a closure in JS that looks like the following:

All functions create closures, they're only remarkable when advantage is taken of them. ;-)

```
var addTo = function(num){
```

I don't know why function expressions are used when declarations are clearer (to me):

```
function addTo(num) {
```

then there's:

```
  var add = function(inner){
    return inner + num;
  }
  return add;
}
```

Which (sticking with an expression) can be:

```
  return function (inner) {return inner + num};
}
```

Then you call it with *new*:

```
var sum = new addTo(1);
```

which causes *addTo* to create a new object that is not used, so you might as well do:

```
var sum = addTo(1);
```

which produces exactly the same result. So:

```js
function addTo(num) {
    return function (inner) {return inner + num};
}

var sum = addTo(1);

document.write(sum(3));
```

However, this is really just a version of [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), so that *sum* will just add the supplied value to whatever was initially supplied to *addTo*.

If you want to add all the numbers from 0 to some limit, you just need a loop, no closure required:

```js
function sumTo(num) {
  
  var total = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
    total += i;
  }
  
  return total;
}

document.write(sumTo(5)); // 15
```

Note that supplying a negative number will result in an endless loop, you should protect against that (I'll leave it up to you to work out how).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
function sum(x) {
  var input = x;

  function add(y) {
    return input + y;
  }
  return add;
}
//var sum1 = sum(2);
//console.log(sum1(3)); // 5
console.log(sum(2)(3)); //5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use recursive instead of loops?

```js
function addTo(initial) {

  function add(adder) {
    if (initial < 100) {
      initial+=1
      return add(adder+initial)
    }
    else {
      return adder
    }
  }

  return add(initial)
}

document.write(addTo(1))
```

As long as the initial values don't go over 100, it would just add with sum of all calculation before + itself + 1.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the `addTo()` function returns another function into `sum` that will add whatever you pass it to the original number (or I assume that's what you meant to write; the first thing to do is change the statement inside of `add()` to use a `+=` instead of just `+` to make sure you save the result).

Since you want to add each number from 2 to 100 (since you already passed 1 into `addTo()`), try writing a `for` loop that runs from 2 to 100 passing each one into the `sum()` function to add them all together. Here's an example:

```
var sum = addTo(1);
for (var i=2; i<100; i++) sum(i);
var result = sum(100);
```

Here I added 100 after the loop since I wanted to grab the final result. You could also add 100 in the loop and use `sum(0)` to get the result without changing it after the loop.

Comment: `for (var i=2; i<100; i++) sum(i);` --- this is a no-op.

Comment: I've also tried this... but the final result seems to be 101 rather than the sum from 1 to 100.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a no-op, since it does actually perform a sum, but I did just realize that what I had thought was a `+=` inside `add()` is just a `+`... I'll edit to reflect

Comment: It does not perform anything: `sum` is a function that does not produce any side effect and whose result you throw away. So apart from heating room - that code does nothing.

Comment: Can you explain a little on why this is a no-op? Thank you. @zerkms

Comment: wait, are you trying to add 1 a hundred times, or add the numbers from 1 to 100?

Comment: @zerkms right, no lasting effect, I already agreed with you on that one. I was just distinguishing from a true no-op, e.g. (function(){})()

Comment: "(i.e. sum = 1+2+3+...+99+100)." --- from the question.

Comment: @fittaoee The problem is the inside of your `add()` function; it uses a `+` instead of a `+=`, so the result isn't being saved. Change it to: `var add = function(inner){ return inner += num; };` so that you're actually updating the value of `inner`

Comment: @kenbellows "The problem is the inside of your add() function; it uses a + instead of a +=, so the result isn't being saved" --- it's not a problem. That's the whole point of HOFs

Comment: @zerkms I mean, that's one way to do it, but it looked to me like fittaoee was trying to play around with modifying private state within a closure, which is another perfectly valid way to do things. Did he mention HOFs somewhere that I missed?

Comment: They did not mention it. But from the function name - the posted implementation is correct. What you posted would convert a function from `addTo` with `accumulate`.

Comment: @zerkms I'm pretty sure this is just a toy example from a programmer who's pretty new to JavaScript. I wouldn't assume too much about intent just from function names.

Comment: Yeah, @zerkms Never assume that function's have meaningful names ;P